# when I use Java Access Bridge to capture element ,but I can't get the element's parent;

Tags: java, java-access-bridge

I use Java Access Bridge to Capture the UI element, I can get the element by the method of GetAccessibleContextAt,but when I want to get the element's parent by the method of GetAccessibleParentFromContext,sometimes I failed,that is to say ,I can get the parent of some elements,but I fail to get the other,for example,In the same window, I can get some text control's parent, but some text, I can't get It's parent， why?

[the image of my window,the red is fail,and the green is succeed,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QGWm.png)

Answer (score 0):

I find the controls that I can't get the parent's is AWT Control,and the Container is Swing Control,So I Can't get Parent or Children, so ,Is there anybody can answer me ,How can I do to get the AWT control in the Swing Container?